# Matlab save doesn't detect char array as string

Tags: string, matlab

I'm trying to programatically set filename of variable I want to save in Matlab.

My code looks like this:

```
   pat='pat_1';
   filename=strcat('mri_realign_BEM_',pat);
   save(filename, mri_realign);
```

Then, I check `filename` to see if the datatype is correct:

> whos filename
>     Name          Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes
>
> filename      1x16               32  char

Looks good so far, but when I try to execute it, I get following error:

> Error using save
>      Argument must contain a string.

On the other hand, if I try to save workspace, with `save(filename)`, it works fine.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's a good idea to [read the documentation for functions you use](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html?refresh=true)

Comment: @excaza Indeed it is and that's the first thing I did! However, the documentation did not solve my issue. I was 100% sure that I do have a string in my function, since a character array is a string.

Comment: It did solve your issue. It explicitly states that both the [`filename`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html?refresh=true#inputarg_filename) and [`variables`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html?refresh=true#input_argument_variables) inputs must be strings.

Comment: @excaza No it did not! The question is the sufficient proof of that. While the documentation does in fact say that the actual name of the file needs to be a string, and that the names of the variables that need to be saved need to be strings, it did so in such a way that despite reading through it for at lest 5 times, I missed it. This is, in my opinion, a combination of badly written error message and not so nicely written documentation. The fact that I'm missing the ticks in variable name was not clear to me until I saw the answer here.

Comment: Yeah, no, the issue here isn't MATLAB. The examples also illustrate it clearly...

Comment: @excaza Look, you can't convince me to believe that help solved my issue when it in fact did not. Yes, I could very well be suffering from PEBKAC or ID10T errors, but that doesn't mean that such issues aren't real issues. The examples and error message obviously weren't clear enough for me and at least one other person, who posted the other question. Furthermore, there are countless questions about programmatically creating filenames. That itself shows that the issue of save is there and obviously isn't as clearly explained as it should have been in documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.
The second argument has to be the name of the variable:

```
   pat='pat_1';
   filename=strcat('mri_realign_BEM_',pat);
   save(filename, 'mri_realign');
```

Comment: That was is! I'll accept this as soon as the system allows.